# Is there a general solution for solving a differential equation that takes the form $y''+ p(t)y' + q(t)y = g(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have to solve the following equation. I have a textbook but I can't seem to find anything regarding second order differential equations with non-constant coefficients. Is there a general solution? For example, the equation I have to solve is $$y''-\frac{2t}{9-t^2}y'+ \frac{n^2+n}{9-t^2}y = 0$$

Comment: For specific ODEs a good starting point is [EqWorld](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode-toc2.htm). The [Legendre equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDifferentialEquation.html) $(18)$ may help here (for $x=t/3$)

Comment: Wolfram Dev Platform yields the solution $y(t)\to c_1 P_n\left(\dfrac{t}{3}\right)+c_2
   Q_n\left(\dfrac{t}{3}\right)$, where $P_n$ is the Legendre P function, and $Q_n$ is the Legendre Q function.